# Discord bot not responding to my commands

Tags: python, discord

When I run this code in replit, the bot appears online in my server, but nothing is printed in the console. Along with that, anytime I try to use the ?roll command in my server, the bot doesn't respond, and no error message is given to me in the console either when I check. I've looked at tutorials on youtube and other sites to see how the basic structure of the bot, with that, I wrote up this code:

```
import discord
import os
import requests
import json
import random
from replit import db
from random import randint
from linecache import getline

length = 1000

client = discord.Client()
secret_token = os.environ['TOKEN']
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We are online as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  
  msg = message.content

  if msg.startswith('?roll'):
    random_word = getline('options_list.txt', randint(1, length))
    await message.channel.send(random_word)
```

Even after error checking my code and seeing the logs, I still can't figure out where it's going wrong. Looking at other forums and solutions, it seems that my code should be working. Is there something wrong with the code? It would be greatly appreciated if somebody is able to help me figure out what the problem is. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```py
import os
from random import randint
from linecache import getline
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?')

@bot.command()
async def roll(ctx):
    random_word = getline('options_list.txt', randint(1, length)) ## define lenght
    await ctx.send(random_word))

bot.run(os.environ['TOKEN'])
```

You must also define lenght and the secret variable with repit secrets (2nd link in documentation part)

Documentation :

- https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html
- https://docs.replit.com/tutorials/08-storing-secrets-and-history